Custom resource provider: Authentication of calls from Azure into the resource provider
How should calls to custom resource providers be authenticated?
From https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/64994#issuecomment-728281972 I got that a certificate could be used. Sadly the response is lacking the implementation of GetClientCertificate. Would this require the resource provider to communicate via mTLS?

Alright, solved it.
So in case your Resource Provider is a Container App, you want to use clientCertificateMode: 'require' for getting the certificate (provided by the service call). Afterwards take the certificate and validate against the given endpoint certificates.

It's great to hear that you were able to resolve your issue. Could you please document your solution in an answer? It would provide clarity for those encountering similar technical challenges within the community.

Alright, solved it. So in case your Resource Provider is a Container App, you want to use clientCertificateMode: 'require' for getting the certificate (provided by the service call). Afterwards take the certificate and validate against the given endpoint certificates.
